# NextJS How to solve "Type 'string' is not assignable to type '...' " error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I have a Button component:

```
interface IButton {
   text: string
   theme: 'primary' | 'secondary'
   size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large'
   onClick?: () => void
}

const Button = ({ theme, text, size, onClick }: IButton) => {
   return (
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        className={cn(styles.btn, {
          [styles.primary]: theme === 'primary',
          [styles.secondary]: theme === 'secondary',
          [styles.medium]: size === 'small',
          [styles.small]: size === 'medium',
          [styles.large]: size === 'large',
        })}
      >
        {text}
      </button>
  )
}

export default Button
```

And I use it like this:

```
<Button text="Click me" theme="primary" size="large" onClick={clickHandler} />
```

When I try to do `npm run build` I get the error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"primary" | "secondary"'.
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you have in your project?

Comment: Related question/answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71370893/9638991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Enum like this:

```js
enum ITheme {
  PRIMARY = 'primary',
  SECONDARY = 'secondary'
};

enum ISize {
  SMALL = 'small',
  MEDIUM = 'medium',
  LARGE = 'large'
};

interface IButton {
   text: string
   theme: ITheme.PRIMARY | ITheme.SECONDARY
   size: ISize.SMALL | ISize.MEDIUM | ISize.LARGE
   onClick?: () => void
}
```

And then use it like this:

```js
<Button text="Click me" theme={ITheme.PRIMARY} size={ISize.LARGE} />
```

Also you can do it another way:

```js
export type ITheme = "primary" | "secondary";

export type ISize = "small" | "medium" | "large";

interface IButton {
   text: string
   theme: ITheme
   size: ISize
   onClick?: () => void
};

export const Button = ({ theme, text, size, onClick }: IButton) => {
  return (
     <button
       onClick={onClick}
     >
       {text}
     </button>
 )
}
```

```js
<Button text="Click me" theme={"primary" as ITheme} size={"large" as ISize} />
```

Comment: This gives me the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ITheme'.` :-/

Comment: I updated my answer. Check the new one.